# convert string to date type

Tags: java, date

I want to convert **string** to **date** format, but the following way didn't work.

It yields `null` for `birth`.

---

```
Date  birth;
try {
   DateFormat formatter ; 
   formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
   birth = (Date)formatter.parse(birthDate);   // birtDate is a string 
} catch (ParseException e) {
    System.out.println("Exception :"+e);
}
```

Comment: what is the value of this birthdate?

Answer (score 2):

Your answer is right on the money.  I put it in a full program and tested it.
It now prints out

```
Default date format Fri Mar 30 00:00:00 CDT 2012
Our SimpleDateFormat 30-Mar-2012
Our SimpleDateFormat with all uppercase 30-MAR-2012
```

Here are some tips:

- Make sure that you are including the correct imports.  Depending on
  what is in your classpath, you may have accidentally imported
  java.sql.Date or some other rogue import.
- Try printing the contents
  of birthDate before entering the try block and verify that it really
  contains a string of format dd-MMM-yyyy

-

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class BirthDate {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Date birth = null;
        String birthDate = "30-MAR-2012";
        DateFormat formatter = null;
        try {
            formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
            birth = (Date) formatter.parse(birthDate); // birtDate is a string
        }
        catch (ParseException e) {
            System.out.println("Exception :" + e);
        }
        if (birth == null) {
            System.out.println("Birth object is still null.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Default date format " + birth);
            System.out.println("Our SimpleDateFormat " + formatter.format(birth));
            System.out.println("Our SimpleDateFormat with all uppercase " + formatter.format(birth).toUpperCase());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sure, I just updated the answer so that it uses the SimpleDateFormat object again to also print out the date in the same format.  The SimpleDateFormat object can be used for both parsing a date and printing a date.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine. If you care to use Joda Time you can use this. You can go through the documentation to unleash the complete functionality in case you plan to use the time for DB testing and stuff.

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
DateTime dt = new DateTime("YYYY-MM-DD");//new DateTime("2012-03-30")
System.out.println(dt);
```